# Using mutiple context in EF 5 for LINQ instead of one large context

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, asp.net-4.5

I am using EF 5 with Code First in my ASP.Net Web Forms App and have created a master context called "Compleate" and when ever I make LINQ calls against it everything works fine. Because the server I am running on does not have lots of resources I craeted smaller context to use to limit the scope of data called up everytime I need to query the DB. The problem is that when I do LINQ calls against the smaller context I always get the error

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: outer

I have been trying to fix this for a few days now and am lost. Any help on what I am doing wrong in my smaller contexts would be great.

Compleate.cs (Context that works and runs Code First Migrations against):

```
using FFInfo.DAL.Tables;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace FFInfo.DAL
{
    public class Compleate : DbContext
    {
        public Compleate() : base("FFInfoDB") { }

        //General Tables
        public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Culture> Cultures { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Section> Sections { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Navigation> Navigation { get; set; }

        //Locale Tables
        public DbSet<Locale_Section> Locale_Sections { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Base.cs (All the smaller context inherit from this):

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace FFInfo.DAL
{
    public class Base<TContext> : DbContext where TContext : DbContext
    {
        static Base()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(null);
        }

        protected Base() : base("FFInfoDB") { }
    }
}
```

SiteNavigation.cs (The smaller context I am trying to read from):

```
using FFInfo.DAL.Tables;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace FFInfo.DAL
{
    public class SiteNavigation : Base<SiteNavigation>
    {
        public DbSet<Navigation> Navigation { get; private set; }
        public DbSet<Section> Sections { get; private set; }
        public DbSet<Locale_Section> SectionTranslations { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

LINQ CODE:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rpBooks.DataSource = PopulateNav("Book", 1);
        rpBooks.DataBind();
    }

    protected object PopulateNav(string Category, byte Culture)
    {
        using (var db = new SiteNavigation())
        {
            return (from n in db.Navigation
                    join st in db.SectionTranslations on n.SectionID equals st.Section.SectionID
                    where n.Category == Category && st.CultureID == Culture
                    select new
                    {
                        LinkAddress = st.Section.Type + "/" + st.Section.RouteName,
                        st.Title
                    }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing one or more of your `DbSet` properties is not getting initialized and in `NULL`.

Comment: If you look at compleate.cs compaired to SiteNavigation.cs you will see the contain the same DBSets. So what would cause SiteNavigation.cs to not initialize one of the sets and how would I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out tonight. If you look at SiteNavigation.cs you will see that I have the private modifier on the SET command for each DBSet. When I removed the private modifier everything worked fine. So my working code now looks like:

```
using FFInfo.DAL.Tables;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace FFInfo.DAL
{
    public class SiteNavigation : Base<SiteNavigation>
    {
        public DbSet<Navigation> Navigation { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Section> Sections { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Locale_Section> SectionTranslations { get; set; }
    }
}
```